# How would I import each line of text in a CSV text file into an ArrayList<String>?

Tags: java

I need to write a method that will import each line of text in a CSV file that has credit card information in it into an ArrayList . Then I will use a StringTokenizer to find the number of transactions, and how many debit and credit transactions there are.

heres the code for the main method:

```
public static void main ()
    {
        boolean moreLines = true;
        int numTransactions = 0;
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            s = new Scanner (new File ("visadata.csv"));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File Not Found");
        } 
        
        while (moreLines)
        {
            try
            {
                list.add(s.nextLine());
                numTransactions++;
            }
            
            catch (NullPointerException e)
            {
                moreLines = false;
                System.out.println("There are " + numTransactions + " transactions");
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException e)
            {
                moreLines = false;
                System.out.println("There are " + numTransactions + " transactions");
            }
        }
        getTokens()
    }
```

The getTokens() method is my StringTokenizer method and i need to input every line of text from the CSV file into it using my ArrayList but i dont know how to do that

Comment: `list` is defined in the main method only, for now getToken can't get access to it, what about passing it as a method parameter ?

Comment: Don't use exceptions for flow control. See CsvReader

Answer (score 0):

You can read a file line-for-line with the `BufferedReader` class.

```java
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        list.add(line);
    return list;
}
```